# [flutter]how to rebuild android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I got this error in my M1 Macbook air :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':image_picker_android:parseDebugLocalResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable
   > Failed file name validation for file /Users/koseongjun/Desktop/caker/build/image_picker_android/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/xml/flutter_image_picker_file_paths 2.xml

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

So I found that the solution is to rebuild my app like this:
[image]

But my navigation bar is like this:
[image]

How can I rebuild my app?

Answer (score -1):

Click to the View option, choose Command-Palette, type view Rebuild